# Property [X] does not exist on this collection instance laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

i am using has many realtions in laravel 5.6 and when i dd the $phonebooks i see all the relations are working properly and every thing is fine but when i try to show them in view i get the error of property does not exist on this collection
here is the relation code

```
public function client() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client','id' , 'client_id');
}
```

and here is controller

```
public function index()
{    $phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->get();

    return view('admin.phonebooks.index',compact('phonebooks',$phonebooks));
}
```

and finally here is how i try to show them in view

```
<tbody>
@foreach($phonebooks as $phonebook)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->id}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->title}}</th>
        <td><a href="/admin/phonebooks/{{$phonebook->id}}">{{$phonebook->description}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$phonebook->calldate}}</td>
        <td>{{$phonebook->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>

        <td>{{ $phonebook->client->title}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/phonebooks/' . $phonebook->id . '/edit') }}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">ویراییش</button>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <form action="{{url('admin/phonebooks', [$phonebook->id])}}" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="حذف"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

and here is the result of dd just a part of it

```
Collection {#630 ▼  #items: array:3 [▼
0 => Phonebook {#572 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "client" => Collection {#627 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Client {#621 ▼
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:16 [▼
            "id" => 1
```

and is goes down just like this .

Comment: $phonebook->Client->title, shouldn't the c be lower case?

Comment: try client not Client

Comment: it is lower case in my code sorry my mistake to type here but tried both and no luck

Comment: try replacing `compact('phonebooks', $phonebooks)` with just `compact('phonebooks')`

Comment: @PhilCross just did it now and no luck yet the same error :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
{{ $phonebook->client->title}}
```

In your view.

You've setup your relationship as a `hasMany` relationship, which will return a collection of models.

If you do `dd($phonebook->client)`, it'll return a collection, not a single model.

It's trying to call the property `title` on a collection object, not a model.

You need to change the relationship definiation to a `hasOne()`, OR do something like:

```
{{ $phonebook->client->first()->title }}
```

(or alternatively):

```
{{ $phonebook->client->get(0)->title }}
```

Comment: {{ $phonebook->client->first()->title }} this just did the trick for me , how i really dont know i try ro read your answer more and more and more and even more to understand what is going on there :) cause laravel didnt just mentioned that in hasMany realtion you will get something like collection object :) thanks to you u saved my day ;)

Comment: Any relationship that has `Many` in it's name, for example, `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` will always return a collection object. When you define the relationship, for example, your phonebooks / client relationship, read it as `Phonebook hasMany Client`, or `Client belongsTo Phonebook`.

Comment: oh i figured out :) that was easy :P thanks you phil you helped me alot

Comment: You could also do something like this which may be more convenient: 1.Change your function name to->clients(), then 2. in your view you can do this-> foreach($phonebook->clients as $client) : //access the client endforeach;

Answer (score 0):

Better to use has()

`$phonebooks = Phonebook::has('client')->get();`

**Querying Relationship Existence**
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations