# View not working with Eloquent Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried making a relationship between two models using Eloquent in Laravel, But in my view i keep getting an error which says it does not exist. The relationship failed to be created as my view can not recognize it. Here is my Code.

Categories Model

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillables = ['category'];

    public function Posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Posts::class);
    }
}
```

Post Model

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillables = ['title', 'body', 'image_path', 'views'];

    public function Categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class);
    }
}
```

Categories Migration

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Post Migration

````
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('Body')->nullable();
            $table->string('image_path');
            $table->integer('views');
            $table->tinyInteger('published');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('categories')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}```


Code in My View
````

@foreach ($Categories->Posts as $post)
{{ $post['title'] }}
@endforeach```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property \[X\] does not exist on this collection instance laravel relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592723/property-x-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance-laravel-relationship)

Comment: $Categories->Posts()->get(), also I think you need refactor your code, in the model is $fillable, not $fillables. Look at the Laravel conventions, I thinks give some handle to that live you no less headeaches (eg. public function posts() instead Posts())...good luck

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `$categories` is a collection, so you have to iterate each item and then do `->Posts`:

```html
@foreach ($Categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->Posts as $post)
        {{ $post['title'] }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: $Categories->posts()->get(); Throws a bad Method call error.

Comment: I did not write that, read carefully my answer